# passing nil value in function of Protocol (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to pass nil value in a function of protocol but protocol gives error: "Default argument not permitted in a protocol method"

```
protocol CoreDataRepositoryProtocol: ExpressibleByNilLiteral{
    func fetchData<T:NSManagedObject>(entity: T.Type, enityName: entittytype, predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) -> [T]?
    func getOne   <T:NSManagedObject>(entity: T.Type, enityName: String, predicate: NSPredicate) -> T?
    func deleteRec<T:NSManagedObject>(entity: T.Type, entityName:entittytype, predicate: NSPredicate, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) -> Bool
    func saveObject()
}
```

The first function , I want to add predicate as `predicate:NSPredicate?=nil` but protocol is not accepting

Comment: I saw a developer Crete an extension which provided a func with the “default to nil” arguments missing, the extension would then pass nil to the protocol func

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you can't provide a default value in the protocol.

Your protocol can declare

```swift
func fetchData<T:NSManagedObject>(entity: T.Type,enityName: entittytype,predicate:NSPredicate?)
```

You can provide a default value of `nil` when you write implement an object that conforms to this protocol

```swift
class CoreDataProvider: CoreDataRepositoryProtocol {

    func fetchData<T:NSManagedObject>(entity: T.Type,enityName: entittytype,predicate:NSPredicate?=nil) -> [T]? {
... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Still its asking predicate while using then function for eg:
CoreDataProvider.shared.fetchData<Student>(entity:Student.self,entityName:"Student")

but it still shows predicate parameter is missing

Comment: You almost certainly don't want `expressibleByNilLiteral` on your protocol definition.  The code in my answer works for me.  Xcode will still suggest the `predicate` argument when you use the function but you don't need it